# Liferay 6.1 theme : jenkins and git

Tags: ant, github, jenkins, liferay, liferay-6

I'm developing some liferay 6.1 themes using plugins sdk, and I want to do continuous integration using jenkins, I have a working jenkins servers with ant installed on it, also my theme project is synchronized with gitlab. The problem here is when I try to build the project using jenkins I have to following problem :

> BUILD FAILED /home/settings/.jenkins/jobs/sample Basic
>   Theme/workspace/sample-theme-2-theme/build.xml:5: The following error
>   occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/settings/.jenkins/jobs/sample Basic
>   Theme/workspace/build-common-theme.xml:5: Cannot find
>   /home/settings/.jenkins/jobs/sample Basic
>   Theme/build-common-plugin.xml imported from
>   /home/settings/.jenkins/jobs/sample Basic
>   Theme/workspace/build-common-theme.xml

and here is my theme build.xml  :

```
<project name="leyton-theme-2-theme" basedir="." default="deploy">  
<import file="../build-common-theme.xml" />
<property name="theme.parent" value="classic" /> </project>
```

I know the project need the build-common-theme.xml which is located on his parent file theme, but I want only my theme project to be in git not the whole directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to commit your entire Plugins SDK to git repository, then you should switch to using maven, because it will be more effort for you to make changes to build.xml files to make it working without the parent build.xml files.

Have a look at [this very good blog post](https://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/creating-liferay-themes-with-maven), and also [detailed documentation on using Maven to develop Lifeary plugins](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-plugins-using-maven-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en).

Comment: Hi, I already used maven to build liferay plugin, but it's too long and buggy. I've fixed my issue by moving plugins SDK to jenkins server and changing building workspace to be inside sdk/themes.

Comment: I've been using Maven based plugin (with and without Jenkins), without any problems for almost a year now. Anyways, good to hear that you got it working.